# Collision problem: placing the centre of rotation of arc on a semi-circle and rotating it till it touches the semi-circle on which it is placed

Tags: matlab, math, geometry

I had previously written a code that allows an arc to rotate about its given center (14,0) but the arc stops rotating the moment it comes in contact with another curve.

This code works when I rotate the arc about (14,0)but not (8.5,0)

I have put rotation of arc inside a while loop by using linspace() to change theta. I used polyxpoly() for finding intersection. Condition for the while loop is that as long as I have empty array the loop continues, but as soon as I get a value from polyxpoly() my loop stops.

code when rotating about (14,0)

```
clc,clear
R = 5;                     % radius of a circle
r = 10;                     % radius of arc
aa = 60*pi/180;              % arc angle
ap = 0*pi/180;             % arc position angle

% defining the semi-circle about the origin

t = linspace(0,pi);
[x,y] = pol2cart(t,R);      % circle data

% Shifting circle centre to (3.5,0)
x=x+3.5;
y=y+0;

% defining the arc about the origin
t1 = linspace(0,aa)-aa/2+ap;
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(t1,r); % arc data

% shifting arc-lower-end to (14,0)
delx=14-x1(1); % Finding the x difference between arc-lower-end x-coordinate & 14
dely=0-y1(1); % Finding the y difference between arc-lower-end y-coordinate & 0

x1=x1+delx;
y1=y1+dely;

theta =linspace(0,pi,500);
i=1;
xc=[];
yc=[];

while isempty(xc)&& isempty(yc)

% create a matrix of these points, which will be useful in future calculations

v = [x1;y1];

% choose a point which will be the center of rotation

x_center = 14;

y_center = 0;

% create a matrix which will be used later in calculations

center = repmat([x_center; y_center], 1, length(x1));

% define a 60 degree counter-clockwise rotation matrix



R = [cos(theta(i)) -sin(theta(i)); sin(theta(i)) cos(theta(i))];

% do the rotation...

s = v - center;     % shift points in the plane so that the center of rotation is at the origin

so = R*s;           % apply the rotation about the origin

vo = so + center;   % shift again so the origin goes back to the desired center of rotation

% this can be done in one line as:

% vo = R*(v - center) + center

% pick out the vectors of rotated x- and y-data

x_rotated = vo(1,:);

y_rotated = vo(2,:);


[xc,yc] = polyxpoly(x_rotated,y_rotated,x,y)
[xc1,yc1] = polyxpoly(x1,y1,x,y)

i=i+1;
end


% make a plot
plot(x,y)
hold on 

plot(x1, y1, 'k-', x_rotated, y_rotated, 'r-', x_center, y_center, 'bo');

axis equal
```

output of above code:

[image: img]

When I choose (8.5,0)  as center about which arc rotates polyxpoly() gives me a value directly in first instance that prevents arc rotation.

previously arc kept rotating as long as while loop was executed. The while loop stopped executing the moment arc came in contact with semi circle. But when I take (8.5,0) as center of rotation for semi-circle(my requirement) the while loop is not executed as polyxpoly() will give a value since (8.5,0) lies on semi-circle so by default arc touches semi circle from start.
Is there any way I can make polyxpoly neglect the initial point of intersection (8.5,0) so that I can make the arc rotate about (8.5,0)

Comment: what does `xc` and `yc` look like when you run it with `[8.5 0]` as the center of rotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`polyxpoly` is useful for polygons with awkward shapes as the math is done for you but for a collision with a circle it is kind of overkill. The math is easy enough to find an analytical solution.

Every point on a circle perimeter, centered on the origin `[0,0]`, satisfy the equation: `x^2+y^2=R^2`

From that, you can deduct than every point satifying the equation `x^2+y^2<=R^2` is either inside the circle or just on it's periphery. That becomes a simple collision test condition. We'll just have to check the coordinate of the last point of the arc at each iteration and find out if it satisfy the condition or not.

Applied in code, for the initial problem (rotation around `[14,0]`), it works as well as `polyxpoly` (and I suspect it is faster).

```
%%
clc,clear
Rc  = 5;            % radius of a circle
Ra  = 10;           % radius of arc
aa = 60*pi/180;     % arc angle
ap =  0*pi/180;     % arc position angle
cc = [3.5 0] ;      % Circle center coordinates
ao = [14 0 ] ;      % Arc "origin"
% ao = [8.5 0 ] ;      % Arc "origin"

% defining the semi-circle about the origin
[xc,yc] = pol2cart( linspace(0,pi) , Rc );  % circle data
% Shifting circle centre to (3.5,0)
xc = xc + cc(1) ;
yc = yc + cc(2) ;

% defining the arc about the origin
[xa,ya] = pol2cart( linspace(0,aa)-aa/2+ap , Ra ) ; % arc data

% shifting arc-lower-end to (14,0) (Arc origin)
xa = xa - xa(1) + ao(1) ;
ya = ya - ya(1) + ao(2) ;

%% make a copy or the arc coordinates (to animate/rotate later)
xar = xa ;
yar = ya ;

%% make a plot
h.fig    = figure;
hold on
% Static elements
h.circle    = plot(xc,yc) ;
h.arcstart  = plot(xa,ya,'k--') ;
h.arcorig   = plot(ao(1),ao(2),'bo') ;
% dynamic element (the moving arc)
h.arcmov    = plot(xar,yar,'g-') ;

axis equal

%% Setup loop parameter
nStep = 500 ;
iStep = 1 ;
theta = linspace(0,pi,nStep);
collision_detected = false ;

%%
while iStep<=nStep && ~collision_detected

    %% counter-clockwise rotation matrix
    Rot = [ cos(theta(iStep)) -sin(theta(iStep)) ;
            sin(theta(iStep)) cos(theta(iStep))  ] ;

    % create a matrix of the arc points, already translated to the origin
    v = [xa-ao(1) ; ya-ao(2)];
    % apply rotation
    v = Rot * v ;
    % apply translation to put the arc back in place
    xar = v(1,:) + ao(1) ;
    yar = v(2,:) + ao(2) ;

    % Determine if the last point of the arc has touched or entered the circle
    % get the coordinate of the last point of the arc, translated so the circle
    % would appear to be centered on the origin
    xp = xar(end) - cc(1) ;
    yp = yar(end) - cc(2) ;

    if (xp^2+yp^2) <= Rc^2
        collision_detected = true ;
    end

    % update display
    set( h.arcmov , 'XData', xar , 'YData', yar ) ;
    if collision_detected
        set( h.arcmov , 'Color','r' )
        h.cp = plot( xar(end) , yar(end) , 'x' , 'LineWidth',2, 'MarkerSize',20 ) ;
    end
    drawnow

    iStep = iStep+1 ;

end
```

Illustrated result:

[image: collision animation]

---

Now this works fine for all position of the rotation origin you define, **except** the one you are interested in: `[8.5 0]`. If you run the script as written above with these rotation origin coordinate you'll see that the arc just rotates but never stops.

This is because in that configuration, the arc end would only brushes the circle at a very specific rotation angle `theta=pi/2` exactly. When the arc is rotated by `pi/2`, it's end is just on the circle itself. The point never goes *inside* the circle. At any rotation angle before or after `pi/2` the point is out of the circle.

The script as it is fails to detect this singular collision point because the way we defined `theta = linspace(0,pi,nStep);`. In all the `theta` values we're going to try, none of them is exactly `pi/2`. So we never gave the script a chance to detect a collision.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

The first way is simple but is only very specific to this problem and might not generalise very well. We just need to redefine `theta` on the interval `[0 pi]`, but with an **odd** number of values, this way we are sure that the median value of the vector `theta` will be exactly `pi/2`.

So replacing `theta` definition by: `theta = linspace(0,pi,nStep+1);` is enough to make the script work on this particular problem:

[image: collision detected]

That is kind of a hacky way to solve it though, because it required to know the exact solution in advance in order to make sure the script would not miss it. A more general way to overcome these kind of step size problem is to include a `tolerance` in the condition.
So instead of playing around with the `theta` definition, on top of the code we'll define a level of Tolerance we can accept, for example:

```
Tolerance = 0.001 ;
```

and we'll change the collision detection condition to :

```
if (xp^2+yp^2) <= (Rc^2+Tolerance)
    collision_detected = true ;
end
```

For your example, and with `nSteps=500`, this is enough to detect the collision even without redefining `theta` (actually a tolerance of 0.0005 would work too). However note that if your basic steps are defined larger (for example `nSteps=100`), then the tolerance will have to be adjusted.

So in summary, I would recommend to keep both implementations for a generic code. The definition of `Theta` over an `odd` number of values, **and** the introduction of a tolerance.

Comment: Thank you sir for your effort , time and explanation. It was really elegant. Sir is there any way we can avoid using equation of circle. In future I may work with shapes that for which boundary will be defined by large set of coordinates for a certain asymmetric shapes for which I will not be knowing the equation. Can you suggest what I will do in that scenario. Thinking of that I used polyxpoly() so that i dont have to bother about equation on which collision will occur.

Comment: In this case it was considered that only end of the arc will first make contact so based on that     xp = xar(end) - cc(1) ;
    yp = yar(end) - cc(2) ; but I was thinking in real world scenario the end of arc may not always make the first contact. If the arc is sufficiently close to circle some point in-between from arc will first make contact with circle. That another reason I was thinking of using polyxpoly(). Any other way where we can do this collision without having to rely on mathematical equations.

Comment: I do not have the _Mapping Toolbox_ so no access to `polyxpoly` to run some test. That said if the collision should detect "_any_" point of the arc inside the polygon then your original solution is already valid: the first point of your arc is already against the circle. It doesn't need to be rotated for a collision to be detected.

Comment: From the online documentation, `polyxpoly` return points coordinates, so if you want to exclude the rotation origin point you could specify that in the condition. Instead of `isempty(xc)`, use `isempty(xc) || xc==ao(1)`. And the same for `y`. It will start to become busy so you might want to introduce a flag like I did `collision_detected` and update this flag at the end of each iteration. This way you can spread the conditions to check over several lines.

Comment: Thank you sir,  I will try it.

Comment: Actually I tried it as per your suggestion and changed the while loop condition as follows: while [isempty(xc)||xc==8.5 && isempty(yc)||yc==0]. The loop is running for few iteration and gives two values but it is showing an error as follows {Operands to the || and && operators
must be convertible to logical scalar
values.
}

Comment: In future I need to apply this code where the arc will move to different places on a ellipse or some other shape and find collision point. If the programmed while loop stops in between I may not be able to find collision points in other places.

Comment: yes at some point `polyxpoly` reports several points inside the circle so `xc` and `yc` are not scalar anymore (they have more than one value), which makes the operand `||` and `&&` fails. If you want to continue this approach you will also have to check for the size of `xc` and `yc` (you can use `numel(xc)` for that). You could try `isempty(xc) || (numel(xc)==1 && xc==8.5)` (and the same for `yc`).

Comment: yes I did that and my code is running. Thank you for the feedback